# SQL CASE in JOIN returning extra rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

**t1**

```
Id        Value
NULL      A
NULL      B
NULL      C
```

**t2**

```
Id        Value
1         A
2         C
-2        Unmatched
```

I want to join on Value, using a `CASE` expression, all rows in t1 that have a corresponding row in t2. For those that don't match I want to default to the Unmatched row (-2). My expected output would be:

```
t1.Id     t1.Value     t2.Id     t2.Value
NULL      A            1         A
NULL      B            -2        Unmatched
NULL      C            2         C
```

However using the following script:

```
WITH t1
AS
(
    SELECT NULL AS Id,
           'A' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS Id,
           'B' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS Id,
           'C' AS Value
),
t2
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Id,
           'A' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS Id,
           'C' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -2 AS Id,
           'Not Matched' AS Value
)
SELECT *
FROM t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
        ON (CASE
                WHEN t1.Value = t2.Value
                    THEN t2.Id
                WHEN t1.Value IS NOT NULL
                    THEN -2
            END) = t2.Id;
```

I get the following results:

```
t1.Id     t1.Value     t2.Id     t2.Value
NULL      A            1         A
NULL      A            -2        Unmatched
NULL      B            -2        Unmatched
NULL      C            2         C
NULL      C            -2        Unmatched
```

I have a simple workaround that will do what I need however my question is why am I getting this behaviour seemingly within my case expression? Removing the second `WHEN` yields the following, which is almost as desired:

```
t1.Id     t1.Value     t2.Id     t2.Value
NULL      A            1         A
NULL      B            NULL      NULL
NULL      C            2         C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, every row matches the -2 row even if it has other matches. If I simplify the ON clause to only show the -2 matches, it becomes clear:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2
  ON CASE WHEN t1.Value IS NOT NULL THEN -2 END = t2.Id;
```

Comment: Yes, because t1.Value is never null it always will show that line, and t1.Value is only sometimes equal to t2.value.

Comment: I understand this, that the IS NOT NULL would be satisfied for all rows, however from MSDN on CASE "The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied" - why is it evaluating the second WHEN for all rows?

Comment: It stops evaluating the CASE statement when it is true for each row it is evaluating. The next row starts fresh.  So the 'A' row matches on 'A' and then a new row has the case statement falling thru to 'A' isn't null so match -2 to -2.

Comment: Why would the 'A' record fall through to the second WHEN though? I would have thought that the 'A' record would evaluate the first WHEN, then stop, then the 'B' record would fall through to the second WHEN? That's what you're saying by starts fresh isn't it? Or does the fact that the 'B' row falls through to the second WHEN impact the result of the first row?

Comment: It returns every row where the ON condition is true.  The WHEN 'A' = 'A' THEN 1 END = 1 row will be true.  So is the the CASE WHEN 'A' = 'Not Matched THEN -2 WHEN 'A' IS NOT NULL THEN -2 END = -2 row. Notice the second one evaluated its condition until the first condition that was true - 'A' IS NOT NULL.

Comment: That makes sense now! I wasn't thinking about the values in the right hand side of the join and how they'd impact the expression - thanks heaps @JBrooks!

Answer (score 0):

As JBrooks pointed out in his answer, your WHEN t1.Value IS NOT NULL will always be true (as t1.Value is never NULL as that is the left side of your join).

Remove the WHEN altogether and just do a ISNULL or COALESCE in the select statement instead.

```
WITH t1
AS
(
    SELECT NULL AS Id,
           'A' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS Id,
           'B' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS Id,
           'C' AS Value
),
t2
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Id,
           'A' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS Id,
           'C' AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -2 AS Id,
           'Not Matched' AS Value
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, ISNULL(t2.id, -2), ISNULL(t2.value,'Unmatched')
FROM t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.value = t2.value
;
```

Results

```
NULL    A   1   A
NULL    B   -2  Unmatched
NULL    C   2   C
```